# 401 in @PermitAll endpoint quarkus

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus

I try to implement a jwt authentication in my api.
I'm using quarkus.smallry-jwt

There is my configuration

```
quarkus.log.level=TRACE

mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=id_rsa.pub
quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=poet
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true
# for jwt expiration duration
com.ard333.quarkusjwt.jwt.duration=3600

# for user's password simulation
com.ard333.quarkusjwt.password.secret=mysecret
com.ard333.quarkusjwt.password.iteration=33
com.ard333.quarkusjwt.password.keylength=256
```

This is my endpoint:

```
@Path("/user")
public class AuthRest {

    @Inject
    PassEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Path("/login") @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(AuthRequest authRequest) {
        return Response.ok(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

But when I Post request localhost:8080/user/login I get 401.

Log in debug only show that authorization header was null

```
2022-09-28 15:06:03,137 DEBUG [io.sma.jwt.auth] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) SRJWT06000: tokenHeaderName = Authorization
2022-09-28 15:06:03,138 DEBUG [io.sma.jwt.auth] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) SRJWT06005: Authorization header was null
```

My understanding may not be fine, anyway any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Hello, could you show us how you call that endpoint ?

Comment: Try the below property :

quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false

Comment: @iabughosh it does not resolve my issue.

Comment: @jacouille I use postman I give a Post that contain JSON body like:
{
    "username" : "test",
    "password" : "test"
}

Comment: @Valgrinde is there any chance you specified any policy for resource access in your application.properties ? if yes, please update answer with these rules

Comment: @jacouille updated the full content of my applciation.properties in my question

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on it, I figured it out.

```
quarkus:
  smallrye-jwt:
    enabled: false
```

Also, quarkus is picking this configuration on build time so if you're trying to specify this one with a profile, you might end up live some warning from quarkus on your logs.